# How to send empty JSON via Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

How can i pass an empty JSON string to Alamofire and send POST request?

I tried like this:

```
let lazyPojo = LazyPojo()    
let JSONString = Mapper<LazyPojo>().map(lazyPojo)

Alamofire.request(.POST, url, JSONString, encoding:.JSON).validate()
        .responseJSON{...}
```

It says that my `JSONString` have to be Unwrapped, but when i run it i got this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: [ ], encoding:.JSON).validate()
        .responseJSON{...} pass [ ] as parameters

Comment: but i need to pass mapped "lazy pojo", so my server could recognize it and do some particular stuff.

Comment: what's the parameter name ?

Comment: Sorry  the code wan't good, but now i edit it. So i need to pass an JSONString as a parameter.

Comment: You are passing JSONString , that's the value, but what is the paramter name for your passing value ?? You didn't mention you parameter name for the value

Comment: Oh sorry. didn't understand at first..i simply named it "parameters"

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't mention parameter name. So check this one :-

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: ["parameters": "\(JSONString)"])
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { }
```